# Get Load Average Net Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, interop, pinvoke

How get Load Average on .Net Core?
I'm try get through P/Invoke and syscall sysinfo. Code show below

```
        public struct sys
        {
            public long uptime;
            public ulong loadavg1;
            public ulong loadavg5;
            public ulong loadavg15;
        }

        [DllImport("libc", EntryPoint = "sysinfo")]
        public static extern int Sysinfo(out sys sys);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Sysinfo(out sys s);
            Console.WriteLine(s.loadavg1);
            Console.WriteLine(s.loadavg5);
            Console.WriteLine(s.loadavg15);
        }
```

but after process make exit with code 139.
How can i get load average?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you're using wrong struct as a result. More info you can get here: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sysinfo.2.html

This code worked for me:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public unsafe struct sysinfo
{
    public long Uptime; /* Seconds since boot */
    public fixed ulong loads[3]; /* 1, 5, and 15 minute load averages */
    public ulong totalram; /* Total usable main memory size */
    public ulong freeram; /* Available memory size */
    public ulong sharedram; /* Amount of shared memory */
    public ulong bufferram; /* Memory used by buffers */
    public ulong totalswap; /* Total swap space size */
    public ulong freeswap; /* Swap space still available */
    public ushort procs; /* Number of current processes */
    public ulong totalhigh; /* Total high memory size */
    public ulong freehigh; /* Available high memory size */
    public uint mem_unit; /* Memory unit size in bytes */

    // This is the tricky part: struct needs to be 64 byte size,
    // so i calculated padding for myself. 
    // At my system ulong uses 4 bytes and short uses 2.
    public fixed byte _f[10];  
}

public static class NativeFunctions
{
    private const float LinuxLoads = 65536;

    [DllImport("libc.so.6", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern unsafe int sysinfo(sysinfo* info);

    public static unsafe string GetLoadAverage()
    {
        if (!RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Linux)) return "Not supported";
        sysinfo info;
        var status = sysinfo(&info);
        return status != default
            ? $"Failed with code: {status}"
            : $"{info.loads[0] / LinuxLoads:f2} / {info.loads[1] / LinuxLoads:f2} / {info.loads[2] / LinuxLoads:f2}";
    }
}
```

Note: linux function uses integer to describe loads, so i had to divide it by LOADS constant which is 65536 in most cases.